# ionic push view from top to bottom

Tags: animation, ionic-framework, transition

In ionic framework when I do:

```
$state.go("settings");
```

I got a transition from right to left.
I want to make the transition for this page from top to bottom, and dismissing it from bottom to top.
Any idea about how to do this ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: any updates on this? @andrewoodleyjr

Comment: nah, im sorry i havent found anything. let me know if you do. I'll keep looking in the mean time as well.